# Como retirar noticias de um blog para a minha Plataforma?

Tags: php, zend

Estou a criar uma plataforma de gestão de propostas comerciais.

No index(sem sessão), gostaria de imprimir as noticias do blog da empresa. 
Estou a usar Zend Framework V.3, e gostaria de saber uma maneira relativamente simples de concretizar o objectivo que visionei para o Index.

Comecei a trabalhar com Zend a uns meses e ainda não estou a par dos módulos que possam existir para solucionar esta ideia.

Comment: Não sei como responder pois PHP não é minha especialidade... Mas pensei numa coisa agora que talvez possa ajudar. O blog da empressa possui um feed RSS?

Comment: Obrigado pela a sua ajuda :) Sim, possui.

Comment: Então talvez isso ajude. [Você pode consumir RSS com o Zend](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.feed.consuming-rss.html). Assim você tem os posts do blog como objetos no seu código PHP, e pode renderizar na sua página como você quiser.

Comment: Obrigado :) Era mesmo isto que eu procurava !

Comment: Transformei em resposta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caso o blog da empresa possua RSS, você pode ler esse RSS com o Zend.

[Documentação da funcionalidade de leitura de RSS do Zend](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.feed.consuming-rss.html) (em inglês)

Assim você terá os posts do blog como objetos em seu código PHP, e pode renderizá-los em suas páginas da forma que achar melhor e mais conveniente. Além disso, você terá sempre os posts mais atuais automaticamente sem precisar escrever código para filtrar por período.